# How do I add text to the price of a variable product in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've managed to add text to the price for a single product, but I can't find any way of adding to the price of a variable product.

Basically, I need to declare the price including and excluding the tax, and I've managed to do this by adding text and a formula to the main price. But I cannot find any way to even slightly alter the price for variable products. If it was not possible, even inserting (ex. VAT) would do.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to insert Ex VAT after the prices. Depending on your theme your prices would all be wrapped in a specific ID or class, so it should work. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp